# Neo4j kernel crashing when loading large graph

Tags: java, neo4j, neo4j-embedded

I'm loading a large number of nodes and relationships into an embedded Neo4j database. After about 10,000 inserts, it dies. If I stay under that point, then everything works great. Queries return as they should, as do inserts. It looks like somehow a database file is getting deleted in the middle of the inserts, which is causing everything to fall apart. My database builds itself from scratch, so if I completely delete my graphdb folder and restart it, it runs exactly the same every time. So how do you handle large embedded Neo4j databases?

Here are the pertinent errors.

**From the Java output side**

The transactions start not committing:

```
WorkerThread exception::org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException::Unable to commit transaction
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to commit transaction
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:140)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: commit threw exception
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:500)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:385)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:124)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
```

Then it informs me that there's a missing file in the database:

```
saction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:560)

at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:448)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:814)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.applyCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:699)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.doCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:631)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commitWriteTx(XaResourceManager.java:632)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commit(XaResourceManager.java:533)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.commit(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:64)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:548)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsDocsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsDocsWriter.java:47)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsTermsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsTermsWriter.java:33)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.java:51)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:85)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHash.flush(TermsHash.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverter.flush(DocInverter.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.flush(DocFieldProcessor.java:60)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flush(DocumentsWriter.java:581)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3587)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3552)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:450)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:399)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(DirectoryReader.java:413)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:432)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:375)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.openIfChanged(IndexReader.java:508)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:137)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.refreshSearcher(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.close(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:811)
        ... 15 more
```

Then I can no longer get a new transaction:

```
WorkerThread exception::org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException::Unable to get transaction.
org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Unable to get transaction.
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.transactionRunning(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1064)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1037)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TransactionBuilderImpl.begin(TransactionBuilderImpl.java:43)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.beginTx(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1024)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: javax.transaction.SystemException: Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.KernelHealth.assertHealthy(KernelHealth.java:61)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.assertTmOk(TxManager.java:339)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.getTransaction(TxManager.java:725)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.transactionRunning(InternalAbstractGraphDatabase.java:1060)
        ... 7 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:560)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:448)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:385)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:124)
        ... 4 more
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:814)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.applyCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:699)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.doCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:631)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commitWriteTx(XaResourceManager.java:632)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commit(XaResourceManager.java:533)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.commit(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:64)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:548)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsDocsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsDocsWriter.java:47)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsTermsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsTermsWriter.java:33)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.java:51)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:85)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHash.flush(TermsHash.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverter.flush(DocInverter.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.flush(DocFieldProcessor.java:60)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flush(DocumentsWriter.java:581)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3587)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3552)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:450)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:399)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(DirectoryReader.java:413)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:432)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:375)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.openIfChanged(IndexReader.java:508)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:137)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.refreshSearcher(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.close(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:811)
        ... 15 more
```

**From the messages.log side**

It starts off getting memory mapping errors. This actually happens first when the database first comes online. But more trickle in before it totally dies:

```
2015-01-27 21:51:29.112+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: [/home/user/graphdb/neostore.nodestore.db] Unable to memory map Unable to map pos=0 recordSize=15 totalSize=1048575
org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedMemException: Unable to map pos=0 recordSize=15 totalSize=1048575
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow.<init>(MappedPersistenceWindow.java:59)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.allocateNewWindow(PersistenceWindowPool.java:656)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.expandBricks(PersistenceWindowPool.java:617)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.PersistenceWindowPool.acquire(PersistenceWindowPool.java:144)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.CommonAbstractStore.acquireWindow(CommonAbstractStore.java:546)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.NodeStore.forceGetRecord(NodeStore.java:149)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreIndexStoreView$NodeStoreScan.run(NeoStoreIndexStoreView.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJob.indexAllNodes(IndexPopulationJob.java:212)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.api.index.IndexPopulationJob.run(IndexPopulationJob.java:107)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Invalid argument
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.map(FileChannelImpl.java:875)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.StoreFileChannel.map(StoreFileChannel.java:57)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.MappedPersistenceWindow.<init>(MappedPersistenceWindow.java:53)
        ... 13 more
```

Then, and I've figured out that this is when everything falls apart, I get this error in messages.log:

```
2015-01-27 21:59:41.516+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: setting TM not OK. Kernel has encountered some problem, please perform neccesary action (tx recovery/restart) null
javax.transaction.xa.XAException
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:560)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:448)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TxManager.commit(TxManager.java:385)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:123)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.TopLevelTransaction.close(TopLevelTransaction.java:124)
        ...
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.store.UnderlyingStorageException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:814)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.applyCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:699)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.doCommit(NeoStoreTransaction.java:631)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaTransaction.commit(XaTransaction.java:327)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commitWriteTx(XaResourceManager.java:632)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceManager.commit(XaResourceManager.java:533)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.xaframework.XaResourceHelpImpl.commit(XaResourceHelpImpl.java:64)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.transaction.TransactionImpl.doCommit(TransactionImpl.java:548)
        ... 8 more
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /home/user/graphdb/schema/label/lucene/_1z6.frq (Protocol error)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.open(Native Method)
        at java.io.RandomAccessFile.<init>(RandomAccessFile.java:241)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory$FSIndexOutput.<init>(FSDirectory.java:441)
        at org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory.createOutput(FSDirectory.java:306)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsDocsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsDocsWriter.java:47)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsTermsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsTermsWriter.java:33)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.<init>(FormatPostingsFieldsWriter.java:51)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.FreqProxTermsWriter.flush(FreqProxTermsWriter.java:85)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.TermsHash.flush(TermsHash.java:113)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocInverter.flush(DocInverter.java:70)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocFieldProcessor.flush(DocFieldProcessor.java:60)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DocumentsWriter.flush(DocumentsWriter.java:581)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.doFlush(IndexWriter.java:3587)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.flush(IndexWriter.java:3552)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:450)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter.getReader(IndexWriter.java:399)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenFromWriter(DirectoryReader.java:413)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:432)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.DirectoryReader.doOpenIfChanged(DirectoryReader.java:375)
        at org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader.openIfChanged(IndexReader.java:508)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:109)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.SearcherManager.refreshIfNeeded(SearcherManager.java:57)
        at org.apache.lucene.search.ReferenceManager.maybeRefresh(ReferenceManager.java:137)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanStore.refreshSearcher(LuceneLabelScanStore.java:159)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.api.impl.index.LuceneLabelScanWriter.close(LuceneLabelScanWriter.java:82)
        at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.nioneo.xa.NeoStoreTransaction.updateLabelScanStore(NeoStoreTransaction.java:811)
        ... 15 more
2015-01-27 21:59:41.519+0000 ERROR [org.neo4j]: TM error tx commit commit threw exception
```

Any ideas on what's causing that .frq file to disappear?

Comment: Could you share the code you use to load the data? And your Neo4j Version, Java Version, OS version etc. Best perhaps a full copy of messagesl.log linked somewhere?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04, Neo4j Community 2.1.5, and Java 1.7.0_65. Here's a link to the messages.log file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BygxKNQH6xZxOGwxTXBLN3JQNWs/view?usp=sharing
As for the code, it's fairly long. Any particular things you're wondering about it? One potentially useful thing to know is that the nature of the loading of the data requires that each node be loaded inside its own transaction. I wouldn't think that would be causing this. I know it's not the most efficient way to insert data into neo4j, but there's no way around it in this case.

Comment: Without the code it's impossible to know if there are any issues, e.g. not closed transactions etc. can you send it to michael at neo4j.org ? thanks

Comment: There are also a lot of other exceptions in your messages.log regarding filesystem/file-mapping issues? Are there any issues with the FS or permissions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We resolved it in a side-conversation, maximum open files was too low (4000) which is also reported at startup.

That causes Lucene to break internally.

After increasing the limit the OP could import the data successfully.